# Changing a "switch" from windows form to WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, grid

We figured out yesterday how to get a listbox's contents to switch between different panels I had stacked on top of each other.  I'm attempting to do the same thing in WPF this time, obviously the syntax is different.  The code worked 100% correctly in the windows form.  I've tried a few different ways to try to get the now "grids" to show, but to no avail.
Thanks in advance!

Current code 'attempt'.  I'm just demonstrating a couple ways I've attempted to change the code there in that first "case".

```
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        // set the listboxselected item to a string variable
        string curItem = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        curItem = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

        // variable changes depening on mouse click, sets to whichever string value is selected
        switch (curItem)
        {
            case "General":
                gridGeneral.Visibility == true;
                gridRightClick.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                gridSnaps.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                break;
            case "E-Snaps":
                gridGeneral.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                gridRightClick.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                gridSnaps.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                break;
            case "Mouse":
                gridGeneral.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                gridRightClick.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                gridSnaps.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                break;

        }
```

Here is the code that works in a windows form

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

```
           // set the listboxselected item to a string variable
           string curItem = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
           curItem = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

           // variable changes depening on mouse click, sets to whichever string value is selected
           switch(curItem)
        {
               case "General" :
            panel1.Visible = false;
            panel2.Visible = true;
            panel3.Visible = false;
            panel4.Visible = false;
            panel5.Visible = false;
            break;
```

etc etc etc....

Comment: You need to include the XAML for the grids.

Comment: This is the first WPF I've tried to create...I have no idea what that means.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't do this the same way in WPF that you would in WinForms

In WPF, you'll probably have a single control in WPF where in WinForms you have 3, and the Template that control uses to render will change based on the `SelectedItem` of your ListBox

Most likely the control definition will look something like this, so that the content of it is bound to the `ListBox.SelectedItem`:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=listBox1, Path=SelectedItem}" />
```

And you can either use `ContentTemplates` or `DataTemplates` to tell WPF how to draw that ContentControl's ContentTemplate.

If the `SelectedItem` is a custom class, a `DataTemplate` would probably be easier, however since its a string in your example, a `ContentTemplate` is probably better.

Here's an example of a style for that `ContentControl` which changes the `ContentTemplate` property based on the value of the Content

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <!-- // Default Template -->
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource GeneralTemplate}" />

    <!-- // Change template depending on a property -->
     <Style.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="Content" Value="ESnaps">
             <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ESnapsTemplate}" />
         </Trigger>
         <Trigger Property="Content" Value="Mouse">
             <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource MouseTemplate}" />
         </Trigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
```

(I may have the syntax of the exact binding you need wrong here... will probably need some testing)

Comment: Thanks you for your time and effort!  :)